# What career path should a programmer who is not good at coding but still quite analytical follow?

Tags: job-search, new-job, job-change, career-switch

I got a CS degree, researched a bit and worked almost 2 years as a Django developer in a startup.

From these previous experiences I have found out I have the following **weaknesses**:

- I may have bad memory / feel a bit uncomfortable or reluctant to learn technical programming knowledge like versions, language-specific features, implementation and low-level details
- I can be slow or may struggle to deliver. I tend to go for more elaborated / 'robust' (sometimes) solutions

And the following **strengths**:

- I consider myself analytical, methodical, structured, problem-solver, introspective. I like to generate theories and methodologies.
- I consider myself creative
- I like to reduce processes and ideas to their basic parts, see how the pieces interrelate

I guess I'm not the only one. There must be millions of 'non-geek' programmers who spend their life coding in a mediocre to decent way without ever getting to catch up other programmers who are just better built for coding (not talking about geniuses, just better coders). So,

1. What environment (startup, freelancing, researching, big companies) / job position may be more suited for this kind of person?
2. Do I need to go through the usual developer life cycle before I can get to a position that doesn't ask me just to code?

Let me know if it's too broad or off-topic.

Thanks!

Comment: I’m a bit confused- you like to reduce processes to their basic parts, yet don’t handle low level details well? Similarly there are other contradictions between your self identified strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: Program manager?

Comment: @JonCuster I meant I prefer higher abstraction level tasks like what a software should accomplish and the best design decisions to do it and not the implementation details (low level).

Comment: The IT world needs more people like you. Unfortunately, it doesn't know it because it's largely run by those 'geeks'.

Comment: I gotta throw something at you that might shock you: you might have ADHD. 
I am just like you (at least from your description), I thought I was just a bad coder or stupid. I often forgot stuff and sometimes got ahead of myself. Turned out I have ADHD and I am not just a "bad programmer". You can actually use this to become better, with some professional help. Unless you REALLY dont want to code. Then I would suggest Team leader or data analyst

Comment: Just a thought: were there any classes in you CS degree that you were particularly good at? That may give you some insight into jobs you would be better suited for.

Comment: @Zeus that's encouraging. Hope I can find a position where I can use my strengths and grow more

Comment: @bibleblade I find this quite surprising. I'm just thinking about how I can have some deep thoughts/ideas but then miss obvious stuff which makes me feel stupid

Comment: @E.Aigle I can remember some like the first phases of any project where I had to come up with a solution (those early software dev phases), database design, defining a protocol in networking classes, etc.

Comment: you should check this out. There are some online tests to get an idea if you have adhd. 
All my educational life (?) I was very good but often failed when overlooking small things that were really obvious. Resulting in things like "this would be an A if you didnt forget this and that, so all I can give you is a B". 
That was one indicator. I just recently discovered this, when I told a friend about how I start a project, become hyperfocused and after a month or so completely lose interest and never touch it again. Another sign, had this checked, and I got adhd. I am in therapy and it helps

Answer (score 5):

I suppose there are some positions as follows.

**1. Test Engineer**

I am not talking about software developers in test, who develop the test softwares or automation test suits. I am talking about test engineers who strictly write and execute the test plans without having to develop or maintain any test softwares.

**2. Product Manager**

If you have a high level understanding of the products, and the workflows, and you can communicate effectively with both the external customers and the software development teams to define the requirements, designs, and implementations of the products, then this position may fit you well.

Answer (score 1):

**Data scientist.**

Your strengths play quite well for the data scientist role. Data scientists still code, but the demands on their coding are not high, more in the good enough to get a task done level.

Note: my answer does not indicate I believe you are not good enough to code. Far from it. I'm just assuming you are right as a basis for my answer.

Comment: If your goal is a Data Scientist, when interviewing for these positions, make sure there are Data Engineers that work with/below you. The last thing you need is to have all these skills and be told to clean up data. A data scientist is useless without data, and a lot of companies will tell the scientists to do data wrangling.

Answer (score 1):

**Software Architect**

The person who defines the software at a larger scale - what the modules are, how they will communicate with each other, and so on.

**Systems Engineer (or Analyst)**

The person who looks across software and hardware, defining what the system as a whole will do, rather than getting down into the detailed coding.

**Requirements Analysis**

Turning an initial request from a customer into a proper formal set of requirements.  This can then be broken down into sub-system requirememts.  This also spawns a set of test procedures to show that the requirements are being met.

**Documentation**

Every good system needs user documentation.

**QA (Oversight)**

By this, I mean the person who checks that everything is done right, as distinct from the test engineer.  Unfortunately, they both get called "QA".  You need to be methodical, and be willing to go through the project documentation spotting things that aren't right.